# Meteor Installation: Meteor Command Not Found

Tags: macos, meteor, installation

I've installed Meteor using "*curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh*" on my OS X terminal but keeps getting "*meteor: command not found*" error when trying to create a new Meteor app using "*meteor create simple-todos*".

How may I resolve this issue?

Comment: What does `ls -lah /usr/local/bin | grep meteor` print?

Comment: bin: Permission denied

Comment: Can you prepend `sudo` to it and run it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue with the path for your **meteor executable file**. First up run `which meteor` command in the terminal. You would get a path like `/usr/local/bin/meteor` copy the path and use the same path instead of just `meteor create appName`

```
someOnes-MacBook-Air:User$ which meteor
/usr/local/bin/meteor
someOne-MacBook-Air:User$ /usr/local/bin/meteor create simple-todos
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've tried running 'which meteor' command in the terminal but no path was returned.

Comment: Just asking, was your meteor installation successful?

Comment: Yes, the installation should be successful. This is the message received:
"Meteor 1.1.0.2 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your convenience.
This may prompt for your password."
I've entered my password and I get the prompt for 'To get started fast'

Comment: Try and find where the meteor executable file is sitting, may be in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add /usr/local/bin to .bash_profile will do;
```

like:  export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin

Answer (score -2):

Try using "sudo" before your command

```
sudo which meteor

sudo meteor create simple-todos
```